# Rails 4 Allow Users to Create and Attend Events

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I found this mini-application on GIThub that allows users to create attend and cancel events here: https://github.com/ghembo/private-events the only issue is that it was made for Rails 3. I'm trying to implement that app into my own practice application but using rails 4.2.4 so far i'm having issues with the attend events functionality.

I have three models that are connected using a rich join using has many through: user, event, and event_registration.

```
user.rb

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :event_registrations
has_many :events, through: :event_registrations
```

.

```
event.rb
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :event_registrations
has_many :users, through: :event_registrations
```

.

```
event_registration.rb
class EventRegistration < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :event
belongs_to :user
```

The functionality that creates a new event is located within event_registrations_controller.rb

```
class EventRegistrationsController < ApplicationController

 def new
   EventRegistration.new(event_id: params[:event_id].to_i, user_id:
   current_user.id)
   redirect_to event_path(params[:event_id])
   flash[:notice] = "Thanks for attending this event!"
 end

 def destroy
   EventRegistration.where(event_id: params[:event_id].to_i, user_id:  
   current_user.id).first.destroy
   redirect_to event_path(params[:event_id])
 end


 private
 # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
 def set_event_registration
   @event_registration = EventRegistration.find(params[:id])
 end

 def event_registration_params
  params.require(:event_registration).permit(:user_id, :event_id)
 end
end
```

This is a snippet of my events\show.html.erb that creates the event.

```
<% if session[:user_id] %>
  <% if @event.attended_by(User.find(session[:user_id])) %>
    <%= link_to "Cancel attendance", event_registration_path(event_id:   
  @event.id), method: :delete, class: "btn
    btn-primary" %>
  <% else %>
    <%= link_to "Attend", new_event_registration_path(event_id: @event.id), 
    class: "btn btn-success" %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The problem is that I do get the "Thanks for attending this event!" message but no new record is made in the event_registrations table at all.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: You have to have a create action and remove the flash_notice under the new action. This is why you are getting success message but not saving.

Comment: The original author said about it: "A Rails app for learning associations". So it is probably more experimental. My advise is not to use it as a base for your own system

Comment: Thanks @Meier but I myself am just practicing rails so this will not go into production at all.

Comment: That is exactly why you should use a good working example for learning, not an experimental one of unknown status with unknown errors (at least one)

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a create action and will need to move the flash notice from the new action into the create.

Your create action should look something like this

```
def new
  @event_registration = EventRegistration.new
end

def create
@event_registration = current_user.events.build(event_registration_params)
  if @event_registration.save
    flash[:notice] = 'Event registration created'
    redirect_to events_path
  else
    flash.now[:warning] = 'There were problems when trying to create a new event registration'
    render :action => :new
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks @Russell, unfortunately the event_registrations controller does not have any view so I get the Missing Template error. New Event Registrations are made directly from the Events show page (events\show.html.erb) when a user clicks the Attend link. Since event_registrations is just a joint table I figured it didn't need to have any views since it just provides a way for users to attend events.